# Get first letter of first and last row in Jasper Reports table

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperSoft Studio in Eclipse to generate a signup sheet for a church. The page header has the label of what last names will be on the page. So page 1 will have A-D, if the page starts with an A, and ends with a D.[image]

This is turning out to be very complicated for such an easy task. I just want to read what the last_name field is in the first and last row of every page, take the first letter of it, and then stick it in the header.

Any ideas are welcome, I am stumped.

Comment: I have kind of got part of what i need. I did  $F{Last_Name}.charAt(0) + " - "      
Which gives me "A - "  but i need to check the last row of each page. When i look at the very last page, it says "Z - " meaning it is checking again at the end on my Last Page Footer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first and last value of a field in a page you use **variables** with **resetType** and set the correct **evalutationTime** on the `textField` (You will need to use 2 textField aligning them correctly one next to the other)

This example will show how to get the **first** and **last** value of the field `$F{Last_Name}` on **every page**

**First value of a field in the page**

The **resetType** on your variable will be `resetType="None"`

```
<variable name="firstValueOnPage" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and in the `textField`, use the variable with `evalution="Now"` (that is default so no tag needed)

```
<textField>
   <reportElement x="30" y="19" width="100" height="20" uuid="e6421031-6db7-4fd9-995f-94cef2eb3621"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{firstValueOnPage}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Last value of a field in the page**

The **resetType** of your variable is `resetType="Page"`

```
<variable name="lastValueOnPage" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Page">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and in the textField use the variable `evaluationTime="Page"`

```
<textField evaluationTime="Page">
    <reportElement x="170" y="19" width="100" height="20" uuid="9100baa5-0095-4dc3-ac79-2cd87562a92d"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{lastValueOnPage}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

To get only the first char of first and last value I see that you have already figured it out, but to complete the answer the textFieldExpression would be

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{firstValueOnPage}!=null&&$V{firstValueOnPage}.length()>0)?String.valueOf($V{firstValueOnPage}.charAt(0)).toUpperCase():""]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Now just put the two textField's next to each other (align them correctly) and you will have the desired result.

Some additional information to learn more about **resetType** and **evalutationTime** (from [jasper report api 6.2.0](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/))

**resetType**

> **None** - The variable is incremented with every record during the iteration through the data source
>   **Report** - The variable never gets incremented during the report filling process.
>   **Page** - The variable is incremented with each new page.
>   **Column** - The variable is incremented with each new column.
>   **Group** - The variable is incremented every time the group specified by the incrementGroup attributes breaks

**EvalutationTime**

> **Auto** Evaluation time indicating that each variable participating in
>   the expression should be evaluated at a time decided by the engine.
>   **Band** The element will be evaluated at band end.
>  
>   **Column** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each column is filled. 
>   **Group** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each group break.
>   **Master** Used for elements that are evaluated at the moment the master report ends.
>   **Now** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated at the exact moment in the filling process when it is encountered.
>   **Page** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each page is filled. 
>   **Report** A constant specifying that an expression should be  evaluated at the end of the filling process.

Comment: Wow you are amazing! Thank you so much. It is so close now. Its acting a little strange right now though,

Its not starting the letter changes until the last page, and then it continues on and tacks on more blank pages, but does start going through all of the letters. I will post images up top.

Comment: in the Page Header. The entire Red bar is in the page header. And then I have the 2 textFields on top of it inside that band.

Comment: Have you done everthing in the answer?, you need two textfields... you need to set resetType and evalutationTime correctly,

Comment: hmm, maybe you have an overflow problem check that the sum of the height's of your bands is within page size - margins...

Comment: I made both textFields use the same expression,

 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{lastValueOnPage}!=null&&$V{lastValueOnPage}.length()>0)?String.valueOf($V{lastValueOnPage}.charAt(0)).toUpperCase():""]]></textFieldExpression>

 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{firstValueOnPage}!=null&&$V{firstValueOnPage}.length()>0)?String.valueOf($V{firstValueOnPage}.charAt(0)).toUpperCase():"" ]]></textFieldExpression>

Comment: Should only firstValueOnPage use that expression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96655/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-webminer07).

Answer (score 1):

Report is ordered by Last_Name therefore we can use calculation Lowest and Highest

define variables:

```
<variable name="lowestFirstLetter" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Page" calculation="Lowest">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}.substring(0,1)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="highestFirstLetter" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Page" calculation="Highest">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Last_Name}.substring(0,1)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and put textFields with `evaluationTime="Page"` into PageHeader band

```
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField evaluationTime="Page">
            <reportElement x="80" y="15" width="100" height="20" uuid="72af3431-eb3d-4f40-993b-4f0733e779cd"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{lowestFirstLetter}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Page">
            <reportElement x="260" y="15" width="150" height="20" uuid="0452517b-5066-4f8a-af6b-f941f1d3c1cb"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{highestFirstLetter}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
```

Good luck